# Exchange Web Service Get Inbox Count NullReferenceException

Tags: api, exchangewebservices, managed

I am trying to get count of Emails received within last 5 minutes using Exchange Web Service. When I run this console, I get NullReferenceException. and StackTrace is not that useful.
Here is what I have so far in my .net 5 console application:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace ExchangeWebService
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Guid SearchTestGUID = new Guid("{AA3DF801-4FC7-401F-BBC1-7C93D6498C2E}");
        private static ExtendedPropertyDefinition customPropDefinition =
            new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(SearchTestGUID, "ItemIndex", MapiPropertyType.Integer);        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>", "<domain>");            
            service.Url = new Uri(@"https://<EXCHANGE_SERVER>/Exchange.asmx");
            var mailbox = new Mailbox("<EMAIL_TO_SEARCH_INBOX>");
            var folderName = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox);
            var view  = new ItemView(120);
            SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5));            
            var results = service.FindItems(folderName, filter, view);
            var count = results.Items.Count;
        }     
    }
}
```

And here is an exception thrown

> Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WrapStream(Stream
> responseStream, String contentEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetResponseStream(IEwsHttpWebResponse
> response)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse
> response)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
> at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute() at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1
> parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString,
> ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling
> errorHandlingMode)    at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId
> parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)    at
> ExchangeWebService.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Temp\ExchangeWebService\ExchangeWebService\Program.cs:line 44
>
> C:\Temp\ExchangeWebService\ExchangeWebService\bin\Debug\net5.0\ExchangeWebService.exe
> (process 34216) exited with code 0

Comment: I would suggest you enable tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications sounds like an invalid response from the server but tracing will let you see the request and responses (or you use fiddler which would achieve the same thing)